# Make a button Default without making it Submit

Tags: html, forms, fancybox-2

I am opening a page in FancyBox (ajax). The page contains a form. I have to submit the data through Ajax only, so I have not assigned any "action" or "method" to this form. The button type is also not "Submit". I can't change it to "submit" because I have to load the next page in same fancybox. Is there any way in HTML5 to make the button "default" without making it "submit" type?

Following is the form I am opening in fancybox:

```
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="scheduleName">Assign name</label>
        <input type="text" name="scheduleName" id="scheduleNamePopup" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" id="theDefaultBtn" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span>Continue</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="cancelFx">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You have given it a class so using some jquery you can actually make it clickable to do whatever you want. -- http://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make it submit type and in the Onclick event after the function affected to it (if there is any) add `return false;` that would cancel the submit behavior 
example :

```
<input type="submit" onclick="yourfunction(); return false;" value="button" />
```

or

```
<input id="but" type="submit" value="button" />
```

and in your function

```
$('#but').click(function(){
    //your ajax code and stuff goes here
    return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<button type="submit" onclick="submit($(this).parents('form')); return false">text</button>
```

With doing like this button first does onclick event which is binded to button, who triggers `submit()` function in jQuery(javascript), and code `return false` after does not allow button to submit form!

Comment: Code-only answers are not as helpful as code accompanied with an explanation as to why this solves the problem.  Please consider adding detail.